# Selecionar meses mesmo sem registros

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select

Preciso selecionar os dados armazenados no banco e separá-los por mês, porém quando o mês não possui dados ainda, o mês não é retornado.

Preciso que o mês seja retornado com o valor zerado mas que traga o mês de qualquer forma.

Minha *Query* esta assim:

```
SELECT 
  (year(article.content_path)) as anoAtual,
  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month(article.content_path), '%m')) AS MES,
  TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(Sum(time_accounting.time_unit)*60),"%H:%i") as tempo_total,
  concat(users.first_name, ' ',customer_user.last_name) as usuario,
  customer_user.email
FROM 
  article,
  time_accounting,
  users,
  customer_user
where 
  article.id = time_accounting.article_id and
  article.create_by = users.id and
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM article.content_path) IN (2018) and 
  users.first_name = customer_user.first_name and 
  users.last_name like concat(customer_user.last_name,'%') and
  customer_user.customer_id = empresa and
  users.valid_id = 1 and
  customer_user.email in (emails)
group by 
  article.create_by,
  year(article.content_path),
  MES
order by 
  article.create_by,
  year(article.content_path),
  month(article.content_path)
```

Obtenho o seguinte retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso preciso que ainda venha o mês de Dezembro, mesmo que ainda não possuo registros nesse mês.
Tentei algo semelhante com o que preciso com uma *Query* mais simples:

```
SELECT
month(article.change_time) as  mes,
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(IFNULL(TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(TIMEDIFF(
(SELECT value_date FROM otrs.dynamic_field_value where object_id in (t2.object_id) and field_id = 79),
(SELECT value_date FROM otrs.dynamic_field_value where object_id in (t2.object_id) and field_id = 78)),'%H:%i:%s')),0))) as tempoDeslocamento
 FROM otrs.dynamic_field_value t2, otrs.article 
 where otrs.article.id = t2.object_id and year(article.change_time) = 2018 and article.create_by = 9
and field_id in (78)
group by month(article.change_time);
```

Porém mesmo assim ele só retorna os registros nos meses que possuem registros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faltou o mês **9** e o mês **12** porém o *IFNULL* não deveria tratar isso?

Comment: Poderia postar seu `create table` e alguns dados de exemplo aqui https://paiza.io/en/projects/new?language=mysql, salvar e adicionar o link  à pergunta por favor?

Comment: Eu atualizei a pergunta @edsonalves porém não consigo fazer essa questão de colocar dados de exemplo e os comando de create table pois não tenho acesso a isso, consigo somente criar `SELECT`

Comment: Apenas reforçando, você precisaria dar um jeito de colocar ao menos o create table aqui ou em algum fiddle para facilitar as respostas, já adianto que é totalmente possível e fácil fazer o que você está querendo.

Answer (score 6):

Experimente desta forma:

```
SELECT      YEAR(IFNULL(A.content_path, NOW()))                                                     AS anoAtual
        ,   MONTHNAME(M.Mes)                                                        AS Mes
        ,   TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(IFNULL(TA.time_unit, 0)) * 60), "%H:%i")    AS tempo_total
        ,   CONCAT(U.first_name, ' ', CU.last_name)                                 AS usuario
        ,   CU.email
FROM        (
                SELECT          1   AS Mes
                UNION SELECT    2   AS Mes
                UNION SELECT    3   AS Mes
                UNION SELECT    4   AS Mes
                UNION SELECT    5   AS Mes
                UNION SELECT    6   AS Mes
                UNION SELECT    7   AS Mes
                UNION SELECT    8   AS Mes
                UNION SELECT    9   AS Mes
                UNION SELECT    10  AS Mes
                UNION SELECT    11  AS Mes
                UNION SELECT    12  AS Mes
            ) AS M
LEFT JOIN   article         A   ON  MONTH(A.content_path) = M.Mes
LEFT JOIN   time_accounting TA  ON  TA.article_id               = A.id
LEFT JOIN   users           U   ON  U.id                        = A.create_by
LEFT JOIN   customer_user   CU  ON  CU.first_name               = U.first_name
                                AND CU.customer_id              = empresa
WHERE       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM A.content_path)   IN (2018)
        and U.last_name                         LIKE CONCAT(CU.last_name, '%')
        and U.valid_id                          = 1 
        and CU.email                            IN (emails)
GROUP BY    A.create_by
        ,   YEAR(A.content_path)
        ,   M.Mes
ORDER BY    A.create_by
        ,   YEAR(A.content_path)
        ,   M.Mes
```

A ideia é fazer um `JOIN` com uma tabela já com todos os meses e depois apresentar a informação de cada um.

Foi colocado o `IFNULL` para caso um dos meses não tenha informação apresentar o valor "0" na coluna `tempo_total`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda João, mas quando tentei executar a *Query* obtive o seguinte Error `Code: 1054. Unknown column 'customer_user.last_name' in 'where clause' 0.000 sec`

Comment: Consegui descobrir o motivo desse erro, precisava alterar a linha da minha condição where de: `and U.last_name LIKE CONCAT(customer_user.last_name, '%')` para `and U.last_name LIKE CONCAT(CU.last_name, '%')`. Porém no meu retorno ele não esta pegando os meses da tabela onde ficam todos os meses.

Comment: O que é que lhe está a ser devolvido no resultado?

Comment: João, acho que apenas precisa de substituir o INNER JOIN por um LEFT JOIN. Caso contrário não vai devolver todos os meses na UNION mas apenas aqueles que têm artigos.

Comment: Sim @bruno, isso será a solução! Resposta alterada.

Comment: Ainda sim esta me retornando os mesmos registros, ou seja, somente quando houver registros

Comment: Não sabemos que informação tem em cada tabela, por isso fica difícil chegar a uma solução válida...

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar toda a sua `query` em um `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(m.id) AS mes, x.*
  FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id
    UNION SELECT 2 AS id
    UNION SELECT 3 AS id
    UNION SELECT 4 AS id
    UNION SELECT 5 AS id
    UNION SELECT 6 AS id
    UNION SELECT 7 AS id
    UNION SELECT 8 AS id
    UNION SELECT 9 AS id
    UNION SELECT 10 AS id
    UNION SELECT 11 AS id
    UNION SELECT 12 AS id
  ) AS m
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT (YEAR(a.content_path)) as anoAtual,
               MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(article.content_path), '%m')) AS MES,
               TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(ta.time_unit) * 60), "%H:%i") as tempo_total,
               CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', cu.last_name) as usuario,
               cu.email
          FROM article a
               INNER JOIN time_accounting ta ON a.id = ta.article_id
               INNER JOIN users u ON a.create_by = u.id
               INNER JOIN customer_user cu ON u.first_name = cu.first_name
         WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM a.content_path) IN (2018)
           AND u.last_name LIKE concat(cu.last_name,'%')
           AND cu.customer_id = empresa
           AND u.valid_id = 1
           AND cu.email IN (emails)
         GROUP BY a.create_by,
                  YEAR(a.content_path),
                  MES
         ORDER BY a.create_by,
                  YEAR(a.content_path),
                  MONTH(a.content_path)
      ) x ON MONTHNAME(m.id) = x.mes
```

Comment: Ele me acusa erro de sintaxe @Sorack, `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (     SELECT 1 AS id     UNION SELECT 2 AS id     UNION SELECT 3 AS id     ' at line 2
`

Comment: @R.Santos faltou listar os campos, já corrigi

Comment: agora o erro passou a ser na virgula, após pedir para selecionar o mês: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*   FROM (     SELECT 1 AS id     UNION SELECT 2 AS id     UNION SELECT 3 AS id ' at line 1
`

Comment: @R.Santos veja agora

Comment: ele não deu mais erro de sintaxe porém o retorno foi todas as linhas e colunas como null

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que sempre serão retornados valores para os *12* meses do ano, a forma mais prática que vejo seria criar uma tabela temporária com os valores já consultados, adicionando uma linha com valor tempo *0* para cada mês *zerado*. Daí seria só consultar o somatório em cima dessa tabela; o que tem valor, somaria duas linhas (*zero* mais o valor total), o que não, retornaria apenas o *0* (pra facilitar, adicionaria à atual uma coluna de mês numérica):

```
--variável para utilização do ano em mais de um ponto
set @anoConsulta = 2018;

--criação da tabela com os dados que você já tem {mesmo select adicionando a coluna criador que é usada na ordenação, e MES_NUMERICO para facilitar o filtro}

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpTab AS (
    SELECT 
      (year(article.content_path)) as anoAtual,
      MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month(article.content_path), '%m')) AS MES,
      month(article.content_path) AS MES_NUMERICO,
      TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(Sum(time_accounting.time_unit)*60),"%H:%i") as tempo_total,
      concat(users.first_name, ' ',customer_user.last_name) as usuario,
      customer_user.email as email,
      article.create_by as criador
    FROM 
      article,
      time_accounting,
      users,
      customer_user
    where 
      article.id = time_accounting.article_id and
      article.create_by = users.id and
      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM article.content_path) IN (@anoConsulta) and 
      users.first_name = customer_user.first_name and 
      users.last_name like concat(customer_user.last_name,'%') and
      customer_user.customer_id = empresa and
      users.valid_id = 1 and
      customer_user.email in (emails)
    group by 
      article.create_by,
      year(article.content_path),
      MES);

-- adicionar à tabela os meses zerados
DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT 1;

WHILE (contador <= 12) DO
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tmpTab WHERE MES_NUMERICO = contador) THEN
    INSERT INTO tmpTab (anoAtual, MES, MES_NUMERICO, tempo_total, usuario, email, criador)
    VALUES (@anoConsulta, contador, MONTHNAME(concat(@anoConsulta','-',contador,'-01'), 0, 'nome qualquer', 'emailQualquer@mail.com');
  END IF;

  SET contador = contador + 1;
END WHILE;

--agora todos os meses estão na tabela temporária, basta retorná-los
SELECT anoAtual, MES, tempo_total, usuario, email
FROM tmpTab
ORDER BY criador, anoAtual, MES;
```

Comment: Esta dando erro de sintaxe pra mim o seu comando. `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT 1' at line 30
`

Comment: @R.Santos foi o `;` que faltou no fim da ação anterior.. corrigido!

Comment: O erro passou a ser agora: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT 1' at line 1
`